# How to set readonly property of textbox from css

Tags: css

i create css code like

```
.inputHide {
    font-size       : 100px;
    width           : 100px;
    height          : 100px;
    border          : none;
    background      : transparent;
    readonly        : true;
}
```

But it does not work. Although if i use font-size of 1px then by using tab i can access that textbox & can change it's value.

Is there any way to make textbox readonly just using css..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with rowland but you can set it uneditable with:

```
.inputHide {
    display: none;
}
```

although this takes it out of the flow (so there is a noticable movement of elements to fill the void your textbox left).

This method makes it completely invisible and uneditable... not just visible and greyed out (like HTML "disabled" or "readonly" attributes would do).

Comment: This is not currect answer. If you set display none, it become such as transparent element and give own place to next dom element.

You can`t set readonly property with css.
It is available only with javascript.

Additional information:
 nodeElement.setAttribute("propertyName", "value");
 input.setAttribute(readonly, true);

Answer (score 25):

For people coming to this answer now. You can do this now with

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: even I make it disable by using css, I can still tab in to it an edit it.

Comment: exactly. it can be accessed using tab button.

Answer (score 8):

You don't set the behaviour of controls via CSS, only their styling - if you need to make it read-only, flag it as such on the actual control

Answer (score 4):

Readonly is not a STYLE attribute. So you can't set with CSS (cascading STYLE sheet).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("select").selectize({
        onInitialize: function() {
            this.$control_input.attr("readonly","readonly");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

css cannot be used for making an input readonly.
You can use jquery or simple javascript to change the prperty of the fields.